# How do check if there is specific text in a class in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I was wonder how I could check if there is certain text in a class in selenium python. The class I'm looking at has the value of `game ng-tns-c606-36 high ng-star-inserted` and because the `c606` part of the class is dynamic, I can't search this all the time. How do I check if it contains `high`? What I'm looking for looks something like this `if (crashClass.contains("high")):` Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Those are 4 separate classes.  You can certainly search for all tags with class "high", and then scan the other classes to see if they fit your profile.

Comment: `and because the c606 part of the class is dynamic`...you are using python, the natural solution since you have access to dynamic content is to dynamically alter your selenium search to accommodate for searchable items...otherwise define a class that you search through based on a selector, but in that instance you'll still need to parse content

Comment: the element's class is "crash1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div//section[1]//cw-crash-games//div//div[1]//span").get_attribute("class")" -- and I want to check if the class contains "high" somewhere in it

Comment: I'm still waiting for an answer...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xpath` like below -

```
My_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(@class,'high')]")
```

Moreover you can also use `in` keyword -

```
print(
    'high' in driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div//section[1]//cw-crash-games//div//div[1]//span').get_attribute('class'))
```

Answer (score 0):

To **find an element with the class attribute containing a specific text**, you can use the following XPath expression:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@class, 'text_to_be_contained')]")
```

- **'*', selects all elements** in the document, regardless of the tag name. You can **replace the asterisk (*) with a specific tag name** if you want to search within a particular tag type.
- [contains(@class, 'text_to_be_contained')] is a condition that checks if the class attribute contains the **specified text ('text_to_be_contained')**. This will match elements whose class attribute contains the specified text, even if it is part of a larger class value.

Similarly, if you want to **search for elements based on other attributes** such as ***name***, ***href***, ***value***, ***or any other*** valid attribute name, you can modify the XPath expression accordingly:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@attribute_name, 'text_to_be_contained')]")
```

- Replace **'attribute_name' with the actual name of the attribute** you want to search within